# How to block/unblock Users in Angular with node

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose

i created Admin panel and add some users in database and show in admin panel . I want to block and unblock user by clicking in block button

`Html`

```
<button type="button" (click)="isDisabled = false" class="fa fa-ban" aria-hidden="true" >
```

[enter image description here][1]

`Componet.ts`

```
changestatus(user) {
     console.log(user);
     return false;
     this.adminServiceService.changeuserstatus(user)
     .subscribe((data: any) => {
       alert('User Disable');
       this.ngOnInit();
     });
   }
 }
```

`Node`

```
exports.isActive = function(req,res){
  user.findbyId(id, function(err, user){
    user.status= !user.status;
    user.save(function(err){
      if(err){
        console.error("Error!!!!");
      }
    })
  })
}
```

`Node Route`

```
router.get('/ban/id',jobProviderCtrl.isActive)
```

`angular Route`

````
    return this.http.get(`${this.uri}/banuser/${id}`);
  }```


Help me


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIj3q.png
````

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html):

```
const adminAccess = function (req, res, next) {
  //write current user query here ..
  if(!user.status) 
    res.redirect('login');
  next();
});
```

Then you can use this middleware in your routes:

```
router.get('/admin/dashboard', adminAccess, loadDashboard);
```